# Drush out of memory when php memory limit is 1024M on my dedicate server. (CentOS)

Tags: drush

This happened when I restarted Apache because my site was down. Normally restarting Apache or other service doesn't break Drush, but today it happened.

I'm sure on my server my php.ini has memory limit set to 1024M, this is my own dedicate server, and the Drupal installation runs well, I check the status report on Drupal (admin/reports/status), the PHP memory limit is set to 1024M.

This happened on my Drupal sites on my server.

When I...

```
[root: sites]# drush st
```

I got

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]
Error: Out of memory (allocated 10485760) (tried to allocate 122880
bytes) in /home/mywebsite/public_html/modules/system/system.module, line 1336
```

I also tried...

```
[root: sites]#  php -i | grep memory_limit
```

And I got

```
memory_limit 1024M
```

Is there anyone has some ideas?

My Server:

- CENTOS 5.9 x86_64
- WHM 11.36.0 (build 14)
- PHP 5.2.17
- Drush 5.8

I've tried `drush status --debug` and it gave me :

> Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 3.02 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01
>   sec, 3.23 MB] [bootstrap] Cache HIT cid:
>   5.8-commandfiles-0-15880291c3f5c759ee66bf106fd77cbd [0.01 sec, 3.24 MB]        [debug] Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.04 sec, 7.43 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root()
>   [0.05 sec, 7.49 MB]                [bootstrap] Drush command
>   terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error] Error: Out of memory (allocated 10485760) (tried to allocate
>   122880 bytes) in
>   /home/mywebsite/public_html/modules/system/system.module, line 1336 [0.06
>   sec, 9.28 MB]

Comment: how many modules do you have installed on the site? have you tried `drush status --debug` to get a more useful trace of whats going on ...

Comment: The memory error is strange because the message says `allocated 10485760` which is only 10M.

Comment: @tenken Thanks I've tried and pasted the result in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your particular setup might be one that (deliberately) has 2 php.ini files:

1. for Apache, e.g. on your server at: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (or similar path depending on your distro)
2. for command line (i.e. for drush) e.g. on your server at: `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` (or similar path depending on your distro)

(I believe that this is perfectly normal kind of setup to have 2 files, I have this myself.)

You need to ensure that `memory_limit` is `1024M` is set for `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`(or similar path depending on your distro) php executed in the command line/terminal/console i.e. drush. You could also try `memory_limit` is `-1` which allows the server to allocate as much memory as is available.

Answer (score 0):

Had a quite similar case here:

CLI PHP had memory_limit = -1

```
$ php -r 'print ini_get("memory_limit") . "\n";'
-1
```

But drush only knows of 128MB

```
$ drush php-eval 'print ini_get("memory_limit") . "\n";'
128M
```

BUT that was my global drush

```
which drush 
/users/bernhard/.composer/vendor/bin/drush
```

Again with the local drush in the current project:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/drush php-eval 'print ini_get("memory_limit") . "\n";'
-1
```

Turned out that the global drush (installed with composer) was in my home folder and in my home folder I had a .phpversion file specifying another php-version for phpenv than in my project dir. So drush used this version with another memory_limt setup:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  4 2021 20:49:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.8.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans


$ drush php-eval 'print phpversion() . "\n";'
7.3.27
```

Hope this gives you the tools at hand to find out where things go wrong :-)